# Window App SDK how to configure uri activation

Tags: windows, winapp

I'm trying to get protocol arguments to point to a specific page in the Windows App Sdk:

```
private static void onActivated(object? sender, AppActivationArguments args) {
        App.GetService\<ILogger\<App\>\>().LogInformation($"App Activated: {args.Kind}");

        if (args.Kind == ExtendedActivationKind.Protocol) {
            var config = teste.Data as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
    
            configureServerOptionsByParam(configName);
    
        }
}
```

But config variable is always null, how toi solve this problem?

Comment: I can't even see where to configure the protocol.  Have you found where to do that?
In UWP it was under the Package Declarations but I can't find that in WinSDK.